# Netlogo: How to create a link with every turtle of a list?

Tags: list, netlogo, nested-lists

I'm trying to link a recently hatched turtle from a breed (a) with the top N turtles of another breed (b). I tried many things but now I'm stuck... My last idea was to create a link from my hatched turtle to every turtle in a list, but it's not working... Here's some of my trial codes:

(I)

```
set rank (sort-by [[feat] of ?1 > [feat] of ?2] breed-b)
;;; creates a concatenated list of turtles from breed-b on 
;;; descending order of [feat] like: [[(turtle 6) (turtle 2) (turtle 0)]]

hatch-breed-a 1 [
         let n 3
         ;;; I want to create-link-with the top n turtles of rank

         repeat n [
           ask self [ create-link-with item 0 (item 0 rank) ]
           set rank remove-item 1 rank
         ] ]

        ;;; my idea was to create a link with the first turtle of the list, 
        ;;; then remove that turtle form the list before the next iteration
        ;;; so that the next link would be created with the turtle
        ;;; that was originally the second, but I receive an error message:
        ;;; ITEM expected input to be a string or list 
        ;;; but got the turtle (turtle 6) instead.
```

(II)

```
set rank (sort-by [[feat] of ?1 > [feat] of ?2] breed-b)
;;; creates a concatenated list of turtles from breed-b 
;;; on descending order of [feat] like: [[(turtle 6) (turtle 2) (turtle 0)]]


hatch-breed-a 1 [
         let n 3
         ;;; I want to create-link-with the top n turtles of rank

         let i 0  
         while [i < n] [
           ask self [ create-link-with item i rank ]
           set i i + 1
         ] ]

        ;;; my idea here was to create an index (i) so that the while
        ;;; would only take the first n items of rank, but apparently
        ;;; item don't accept a variable (i) only numbers.
```

I appreciate any help with this, thanks!

Comment: You can shorten `(sort-by [[feat] of ?1 > [feat] of ?2] breed-b)` to just `reverse sort-on [feat] breed-b` or `sort-on [(- feat)] breed-b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the hatched to

```
create-links-with max-n-of n breed-b [feat]
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I don't know why, but the hatched turtle creates links with all members of breed-b, not only the top n.

Comment: That does not happen if you execute this code once per hatched turtle with the correct value for `n`. (You can test by putting `show count my-links` right after the line creating the links.) You'll have to post your code to see what you are doing wrong.  Probably you are executing this code repeatedly while changing the `feat` values.

Comment: You are correct, the list ordered by `feat` was defined outside the `repeat` brackets and the hatched turtle was creating links with the top `n` of breed-b list, which were being removed after at the end of the iteration so that in the next one the hatched turtle created links with the next top `n` turtles. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way for code (I) to work:

```
repeat n [ 
  ask self [ 
    create-share-with (first rank) ] 
  set rank but-first rank 
  ]
```

Comment: `ask self` is always redundant, so you can just get rid of that part.

Comment: You're correct! Thank you for the tip, my code is more clean now :D